# How to determine current foreground app name in Marshmallow?

Tags: android, foreground

I am trying to identify the current foreground application name in Marshmallow (check below image).

[image]

==========================================

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

packagename = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

==========================================

But it seems that `getRunningTasks()` has been deprecated. Can you please suggest an alternate way for this.

Comment: you can atleast write the code here

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that works from Kitkat version and above which is tested by me. (I haven't tested prior 4.4).

**1.** Declare permissions in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

**2.** Create a foreground service.

**a.** In onCreate of Service:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForeground();
        }

        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        printForegroundTask();
                   }
                });
            }

        };
        //Starts after 0 sec and will repeat on every 5 sec of time interval.
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000);
```

**b.** The method which prints the log of the package name of the foreground app:

```
private void printForegroundTask() {

        String currentApp = "NULL";
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time - 1000*1000, time);
            if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
                SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
                for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                    mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                }
                if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                    currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                }
            }
        } else {
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Current App in foreground is: " + currentApp);
    }
```

**3.** Once app is installed. Get this **Usage Access** Permission for your application:
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4YIP.png)

You are good to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `am.getAppTasks().get(0).getTaskInfo().topActivity` for your current app.
If you want process level info like process name then you can use
`am.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am looking for any other application, not the one belonging to my current app.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to get current foreground app working mostly

```
private void printForegroundTask() {

String currentApp = "NULL";
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time - 1000*1000, time);
        if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }
            if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
            }
        }
    } else {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        currentApp = tasks.get(0).processName;
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Current App in foreground is: " + currentApp);
}
```